# Dynamically update JSON files based on config

Tags: python

Suppose I have a config file like this where I list a bunch of values. I am running a function in which I am checking that a set of strings will always begin with one of these defined values.

```
start_values = [
    "cats",
    "dogs",
    "birds",
    "horses"
]
```

And I also have a json file on which I want run unit tests on to make sure that my function is running properly, like this.

```
{
    "sentence_tests": [
        "horses eat grass.",
        "birds fly high.",
        "cats like to nap.",
        "dogs are cool."
    ]
}
```

However, the problem I am facing is that if I want to change one of my start_values to be something else, I want to also update my json file for that specific value. For example, if I change "dogs" to "cows", I want that to update automatically in my json file instead of having to do that manually.

So this is how I would want it to be after I change the start_values:

Modified start_values:

```
start_values = [
    "cats",
    "cows",
    "birds",
    "horses"
]
```

Modified json file:

```
{
    "sentence_tests": [
        "horses eat grass.",
        "birds fly high.",
        "cats like to nap.",
        "cows are cool."
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: In your first sentence, "like this" is unclear. What do you mean? Even more, you seem to only want to read/modify/write JSON, for which Python comes equipped with a module already.

Comment: Yes, it's possible in python. What triggers the change to the JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

with open(filename, "rt") as f:
    sentences = json.loads(f.read())

for i, value in enumerate(starts_values):
    words = sentences["sentences_tests"][i].split()
    if words[0] != value:
        words[0] = value
    words = " ".join(words)
    sentences["sentences_tests"][i] = words

with open(filename, "wt") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(sentences, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

you can easily load a JSON object using the [json python library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). It will transform into a python dictionary. All you have to do after this is rewrite the file.